# Parameterless default constructor error when using autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have no idea why this is not working.
I have copied (where possible) my **Startup.cs** from another project that works fine, but for some reason this will not work.

The **Startup.cs** looks like this:

```
public partial class Startup
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures our API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The Application to configure</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        // Get our server options
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var container = ConfigureInversionOfControl(app, config);
        var scope = config.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
        var serverOptions = ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app, scope);

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds
        // Autofac-injected middleware registered with the container.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);           
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);


        // Configure our application
        ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
        ConfigureWebApi();

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure our web api
    /// </summary>
    private static void ConfigureWebApi()
    {

        // Register all areas
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures Autofac DI/IoC
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The Application to configure</param>
    /// <param name="config">The HttpConfiguration</param>
    private static IContainer ConfigureInversionOfControl(IAppBuilder app, HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Create our container
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // You can register controllers all at once using assembly scanning...
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Register our module
        builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());

        // Build
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Lets Web API know it should locate services using the AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver
        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Return our container
        return container;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to create the UserService per request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The Application to configure</param>
    /// <param name="scope">The current scope</param>
    private static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(IAppBuilder app, ILifetimeScope scope)
    {

        // Get our providers
        var authProvider = scope.Resolve<OAuthProvider>();
        var refreshTokenProvider = scope.Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();
        var config = scope.Resolve<PiiiCKConfig>();

        // Create our OAuth options
        return new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/access_token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AccessTokenFormat = new Web.Authentication.JwtFormat(config),
            Provider = authProvider,
            RefreshTokenProvider = refreshTokenProvider
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to configure token consumption
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The Application to configure</param>
    private static void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        // Create our variables
        const string issuer = "https://localhost:44347";
        var audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        var audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);
        var jwtBearerAuthenticationOptions = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
            {
                new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
            }
        };

        // Use JWT to authorize requests
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerAuthenticationOptions);
    }
}
```

But when I make any request to any of my controllers, I get this error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CategoriesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

The **CategoriesController** just has one dependency:

```
// Readonly properties
private readonly ICategoryProvider _provider;

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
public CategoriesController(ICategoryProvider provider)
{
    _provider = provider;
}
```

And the **CategoryProvider** has this constructor:

```
// Fields
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
private readonly ICategoryService _service;

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
public CategoryProvider(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ICategoryService service)
{

    // Map our properties
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _service = service;
}
```

My module looks like this:

```
public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {

        // Create our Singletons
        builder.RegisterType<PiiiCKConfig>().As<PiiiCKConfig>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<EncryptionProvider>().As<IEncryptionProvider>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<OAuthProvider>().As<OAuthProvider>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<RefreshTokenProvider>().As<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<StripeProvider>().As<IStripeProvider>().SingleInstance();

        // InstancePerLifetimeScope
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<UserProvider>().As<IUserProvider>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Create our services (per dependancy)
        builder.RegisterType<AnswerService>().As<IAnswerService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<AttributeService>().As<IAttributeService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<CategoryService>().As<ICategoryService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<ClaimService>().As<IClaimService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<ClientService>().As<IClientService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<CriteriaService>().As<ICriteriaService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<FeedService>().As<IFeedService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<FormulaService>().As<IFormulaService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<GroupService>().As<IGroupService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<QuestionService>().As<IQuestionService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<QuoteService>().As<IQuoteService>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<RefreshTokenService>().As<IRefreshTokenService>().InstancePerDependency();

        // Create our providers
        builder.RegisterType<AnswerProvider>().As<IAnswerProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<AttributeProvider>().As<IAttributeProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<CategoryProvider>().As<ICategoryProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ClaimProvider>().As<ClaimProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ClientProvider>().As<IClientProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<CriteriaProvider>().As<ICriteriaProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<FeedProvider>().As<IFeedProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<FormulaProvider>().As<IFormulaProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<GroupProvider>().As<IGroupProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<QuestionProvider>().As<IQuestionProvider>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ApiAiProvider>().As<IApiAiProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<PiiikProvider>().As<IPiiikProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ProductProvider>().As<IProductProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SettingProvider>().As<ISettingProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<TrackingProvider>().As<ITrackingProvider>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Users
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<User>(c.Resolve<DbContext>())).As<IUserStore<User>>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<UserProvider>() { DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(c.Resolve<PiiiCKConfig>().Issuer) }).InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you're creating an instance of the `CategoriesController` class (possibly in `builder.RegisterApiControllers`?), but the error message is pretty clear. You should either create a parameterless constructor for it, or pass an `ICategoryProvider` to the constructor.

Comment: Have you used autofac before? Yes RegusterApiControllers registeres all the controllers in the Assembly. And RegisterModule adds all my services/proivders to the scope so that when my CategoriesController is invoked, the ICategoryProvider is instantiated and passed to the controller. That is what is supposed to happen, but it isn't. I am asking why isn't it?

Comment: Ah, ok. No, haven't used autofac before, so this is new to me.